# Converting csv to xml in groovy

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

I need to convert a csv file to xml in the following format:

The input csv is

```
scott,male,26,doctor
ryan,male,20,student
laura,female,30,lawyer
```

The resulting xml should be

```
<root>
<criteria name="scott" sex = "male" age = "26" profession = "doctor"/>
<criteria name="ryan" sex = "male" age = "20" profession = "student"/>
<criteria name="laura" sex = "female" age = "30" profession = "lawyer"/>
<root/>
```

and in the csv if any field is missing like profession,

```
laura,female,30
```

the resulting xml should be

```
<criteria name="laura" sex = "female" age = "30"/>
```

if the csv is :

```
 laura,female,,lawyer
```

it produces

```
<criteria name="laura" sex = "female" age = "" profession = "lawyer"/>
```

where as i want the xml to be

```
 <criteria name="laura" sex = "female" profession = "lawyer"/>
```

Can some one help me out with the code to do that in groovy?

The code i am using is

```
CommonsMultipartFile multiPartFile=fileList.first()
                params.type = 'text/csv'
                if(CSV_MIME_TYPE.contains(params.type)){
                    InputStream  inputStream= multiPartFile.getInputStream()
                    def writer=new StringWriter()
                    def xmlBuilder= new MarkupBuilder(writer)
                    xmlBuilder.setDoubleQuotes(true)
                    xmlBuilder.root(){  
                        inputStream.eachLine{ line->
                            def a,b,c,d,e,f,g
                            (a,b,c,d) = line.split(',',-1)
                                      criteria(name:a,sex:b,age:c,profession:d)
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to get rid of the empty fields there would be use another mapping approach.  if the empty values are not in the map for the `criteria()` call, then nothing is generated there.  so you could map and filter them like this:

```
def line = 'laura,female,,lawyer'
def mapping = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'profession']
// use criteria instead of println there
println([mapping,line.split(',',-1)*.trim()].transpose().findAll{it[1]}.collectEntries())
//=> [name:laura, sex:female, profession:lawyer]
```

`transpose` pairs the keys from the mapping together with the values from the line (it only takes the same amount of each list, so missing data at the end of the line is no problem); next filter all emtpy values out and finally `collectEntries` turns those into a map

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected but there is an extra comma in the CSV snippet `laura,female,,lawyer` which is throwing off your CSV 'parser'.

The abbreviation of your code works as expected, here it is in [Groovy web console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5736449051721728) (click 'execute script' and then open the 'output' tab - if the console loads up empty, try reloading it).